# What is the correct way to hide files using node-debug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I've been trying to hide two or more files using '--hidden' option but so far it only seems to work with one file.

I know it might be something silly that I might be missing but I'm desperate and I just want to make it work and understand exactly how it works.

So far I have tried the following commands in CMD:

```
 node-debug --hidden="source2.js" --hidden="script-min.js" main.js
 node-debug --hidden="source2\.js" --hidden="script-min\.js" main.js
 node-debug --hidden source2.js --hidden script-min.js main.js
 node-debug --hidden source2\.js --hidden script\-min\.js main.js
 node-debug --hidden="source2.js" --hidden="script-min.js" main.js
 node-debug --hidden='["source2.js","script-min.js"]' main.js
 etc... removing/adding simple and double quotes and escaping characters.
```

And it works when I hide one file for example:

```
node-debug --hidden="source2.js" hello-world-server.js
node-debug --hidden source2.js hello-world-server.js
```

I'm not looking for a regex to hide both files I'm looking for the correct way to use two regex using '--hidden' option in CMD

I already searched and try different things but nothing seems to be working for me.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance I appreciate your help!.

Comment: Possibly relevant reading material: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#how-do-i-specify-files-to-hide

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, I tried everything in the documentation and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I have been testing complex regexes as well without any luck